# Firebase Auth to sign-in google not working in Framework7

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, html-framework-7

I have setup Firebase admin structure and generate all required id, key and token. With Firebase email and password auth it works fine. But when implementing Google signin it fails. Please help.

**index.html code**

```
`<a href="#" class="googleplus" onclick="firebaselogin()"><i class="icon fab fa-google-plus-g"></i></a>`
<script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="js/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var configfirebase = {
    apiKey: "***********************",
    authDomain: "*****************.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://f*************.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "************",
    storageBucket: "************",
    messagingSenderId: "**********",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(configfirebase);
</script>
```

**registration.js code**

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
function firebaselogin() {
  firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function() {
          return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
        }).then(function(result) {
          var token = result.credential.accessToken;
          var user = result.user;
         app.dialog.alert('Login success!! Welcome:' + result.user );
        }).catch(function(error) {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
         app.dialog.alert('Login error!! error:' + errorMessage );

        });
}
```

When I run the app I get this error.[image]

Comment: make sure your register.js is linked after firebase js files. if you did try linking the firebase js files from a CDN link

Comment: Yes you are right. I have fixed that issue by just placing the firebase-app js to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed that issue by just placing the firebase-app js to top.